# How can I access the LaTeX commands from the terminal?

Tags: terminal, macos

I just installed [MacTeX](https://www.tug.org/mactex/) onto Yosemite and it installed everything in `usr/local/texlive`

However if I am in Terminal and try to compile a LaTeX file with `pdflatex foo.tex`, it cannot find the LaTeX tools. Further `whereis pdflatex` returns no results.

If I specify the entire path of `pdflatex` (e.g., `/usr/local/texlive/2014/.../bin/pdflatex`) it all works well.

How can I get the LaTeX tools to work from the terminal without specifying the entire path?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For binaries to be accessible from the command line, their locations must be part of the `PATH` environment variable. If you do the following

```
PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/texlive/2014/.../bin
```

(filling in the correct path), you will be able to call `pdflatex` directly (as well as every other program in the same directory. To make the change permanent, `export` the command in a file sourced by the shell, such as `.bash_login` or `.profile` (assuming you use bash).
Either use an editor or run

```
echo "export PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/texlive/2014/.../bin" >> ~/.bash_login
```

Which will append the output of the `echo` command to the file and create it if it does not exist.

The shell searches the directories in the `PATH` in the order they are listed, so usually it is a good idea to always *append* to the `PATH` unless you know exactly what is in the added directory. It might contain other executables with the same name as other programs which are already in the `PATH`. Having these shadowed can sometimes lead to surprises.

Answer (score 3):

To get the LaTeX tools to run from the command line, you need to add the path to your `pdflatex` to your executable search path. To do this, you'll need to edit the `.bash_profile` file in your home directory. Open the file in a plain text editor (e.g. vi, emacs, bbedit) and add this line at the bottom:

```
PATH=/usr/local/texlive/2014/.../bin:$PATH
```

where `/usr/local/texlive/2014/.../bin` is the path you typed in your example to get pdflatex to run.

---

**An aside**

`whereis` only returns results from system-installed executables. `which` looks in the entire path. e.g. on my machine:

```
~ 503   whereis ruby
/usr/bin/ruby
~ 504   which ruby
/Users/steve/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/bin/ruby
```